# Scroll an image to the exact 'y' location in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to HTML, CSS, and JS coding. I want to create an image view with multiple images. I have the locations of the words from these images using OCR. I want to create a function that can take the word as an argument, get the location from a global variable output of the OCR and scroll the image/s to the right location.

For example:
Assume we have the following images in a view/container in html. I have the details of all the files including their OCR output from tesseract.

image 1: https://d.novoresume.com/images/doc/minimalist-resume-template.png
image 2: https://www.jobseeker.com/api/media/documents/1cdf7944-6cab-4422-8b39-7ee580688d78/Resume-example-Circulair.svg?v=1650285945478
image 3: https://s3.resume.io/cdn-cgi/image/width=544,height=480,fit=crop,gravity=top,quality=75,format=auto/uploads/local_template_image/image/389/persistent-resource/new-york-resume-templates.jpg
image 4: https://cdn-images.zety.com/templates/zety/valera-11-classic-silver-dark-332@3x.png

Now, I want to create a function that on receiving a word as input can scroll the container to the right image and the right position. Like, for a word that's at the left side of the image, starting a sentence/paragraph,  should scroll up to the top 1/3rd part of the view to bring that particular line/para in focus.

Apologies, if I'm unable to provide a better explanation or any code samples for it; I don't have any yet. Though I hope my intent is clear with the example above

Comment: What if the same word is present in 2 different images? or in the 4? What is your expected behaviour? Thanks

Comment: For every occurrence, it has coordinates from the image. BTW I solved this, made some calculations in the changed resolution of the images stacked in div, and added scrollTo to the div to the exact location of the word. Worked like a charm.